# Looking for clarity on this answer involving logical operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I'm working on a homework problem and I already got the answer correct, but it was the result of adding operators out of frustration so I'm hoping someone can clarify this for me.

I'm testing to see if a number is positive or negative, return 1 if x > 0, return 0 otherwise. Only using the bit operations ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Here's my answer:  !(x >> 31 | !x)

When I work this out on paper my understanding of it falls apart.

1. move the sign bit all the way to the right
2. OR that bit with !x

   - positive would be 0 | 1
   - negative would be 1 | 0
3. ! the result, which always, not matter what, ends up as 0

   - !(0 | 1) = 0
   - !(1 | 0) = 0

What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: `!` is the boolean not. The bitwise-not is `~`. No matter what sign `x` has, if it's not zero then `!x` is zero.

Comment: Why would a positive x cause !x = 1?

Comment: Hunter - !0 = 1 right? So if x is positive(0) !x = 1. Right?

Comment: @jlee when you do `x >> 31`, you get a value derived by shifting the value in x by 31 bits... but you don't change the actual `x`.  So `!x` operates on the original value in x, not the shifted value from `x >> 31`.  So `!x` only gives `1` when x was 0.

Comment: @Dmitri Thank you for that explanation, I understand where I was getting confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're off is in #2:

- if x is positive, x >> 31 == 0 and !x == 0 so !(0 | 0) == 1
- if x is negative, x >> 31 == 1 and !x == 0 so !(1 | 0) == 0
- if x is zero, x >> 31 == 0 and !x == 1 so !(0 | 1) == 0

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm still confused about why, for x is positive, !x = 0. If x is positive, the sign bit would be 0. So wouldn't !0 = 1?  Or am I completely understanding this wrong

Comment: @jlee If x is positive, then it is not zero. You are confusing x with x>>31.

Comment: `!` is the logical negation operator.  So in a boolean context !x will be 1 if x is 0 and !x will be 0 if x is non-zero

Comment: I see where I was wrong. For some reason I was thinking the value of x was being changed to its sign bit and I was doing sign bit | !sign bit, which of course was wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for :

```
size_t shift = sizeof(x) * 8 - 1;
bool ans = x | ~(1 << shift);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. My answer is correct (at least the testing script says so). I'm just looking for a little clarification on where I was wrong in my reasoning

Comment: To avoid implementation-defined behavior, it's also advisable to cast `x` to an unsigned type.